# Users can't login to WordPress Admin Dashboard

Tags: wordpress, authentication, admin

My admin users can't login to the admin back-end of our (IIS) WordPress site. After login they are simply redirected to the homepage.

I've tried every solution I can find on Google. I've tried on Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE. I can currently login in Chrome, but not any other browser. I don't even want to logout in Chrome in case we are left with absolutely no admin access.

How can I even find out what the actual problem is? Setting WP_DEBUG does nothing.

Please help!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I just migrated Joomla users to Wordpress using a plugin and now my admin accounts no longer have access to wp-admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add some closure to this issue. We have regained admin access, but I don't know specifically what either caused the problem or fixed it. I suspect changes to our firewall rules though.